# control the rotation of an object based on the position of another object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on a project where I'm using mediapipe to perform hand-tracking in unity. Now I want to control the 3D model of a hand which I've modelled and rigged in blender. I've received the mediapipe data and projected them as 21 points in unity. These points move based on the mediapipe data which is translated into the localPosition of these points.

Now I want to move the fingers of the hand based on the information from these points. I tried changing the rotation.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class control_bones : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public Transform wristL; 
    public Transform index1L;
    public GameObject manager; 
    private Transform point0;
    private Transform point5;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10.0f;
    private Vector3 lastPosition;
    private void Start()
    {
        manager = GameObject.Find("Manager");
       
        if (manager != null)
        {
            point0 = manager.transform.Find("Hand/Points/point (0)");
            point5 = manager.transform.Find("Hand/Points/point (5)");
            if (point0 == null || point5 == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("The 'point0' or 'point6' Transform was not found within the 'Manager' hierarchy.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("The 'manager' reference is not set. Please assign the 'Manager' GameObject in the Inspector.");
        }

        wristL = transform.Find("LP_Hands/wrist.L");
        index1L = transform.Find("LP_Hands/wrist.L/hand.L/index.L/index1.L");

       
        if (wristL == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("not found");
        }

        lastPosition = point5.localPosition;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
       
        if (wristL != null && point0 != null)
        {
            wristL.position = point0.position;
            Vector3 positionChange = point5.localPosition - lastPosition;
            Quaternion rotationToApply = Quaternion.Euler(positionChange * rotationSpeed);
            index1L.rotation = rotationToApply;
            lastPosition = point5.localPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not working.

Ss there any other approach to do the same. I'm new to unity, any guidance and help will be great.

Thanks in advance